# How to change focus of simpledialog in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, simpledialog

I have several `simpledialog` popup windows. The first one that shows is in focus and after it closes then every single one after that is not in focus. The `simpledialog` code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
    
def doing_stocks():
    name = myaskstring("Input data", "Enter box number:", parent = root)
    name2 = myaskstring("Input data2", "Enter box number2:", parent = root)
    name3 = myaskstring("Input data3", "Enter box number3:", parent = root)

class My_QueryString(tk.simpledialog._QueryString):

      def body(self, master):
          self.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.ok)
          self.bind('<Return>', self.ok)
          w = Label(master, text=self.prompt, justify=LEFT)
          w.grid(row=0, padx=5, sticky=W)

          self.entry = Entry(master, name="entry")
          self.entry.grid(row=1, padx=5, sticky=W+E)

          if self.initialvalue is not None:
              self.entry.insert(0, self.initialvalue)
              self.entry.select_range(0, END)

          root.update_idletasks()
          self.entry.focus_force()
          return self.entry

def myaskstring(title, prompt, **kw):
    d = My_QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
    root.update_idletasks()
    answer = d.result 
    d.destroy()
    return answer
   
root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x761")
label1 = Label(root, text="")
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)

button2 = Button(root, text = "Doing Stocks", command=doing_stocks).place(x = 300, y = 340)

root.mainloop()
```

This is a simplified version of the code. I call my `simpledialog` popups like this:

```
myaskstring("Title", "Prompt", parent = root)
```

In the `doing_stocks()` method the first time I call `myaskstring` the window and the entry field will be in focus then all times after that it won't be. How can I make every `simpledialog` be in focus when it appears on the screen?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: @martineau I updated the code example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, the minimal reproducible example you added was helpful — thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree is seems odd that the focus isn't set to each `My_QueryString` instance when it's initialized. Regardless of the reason why, a workaround for it not happening is to bind a `<Map>` event handler function to the dialog's `Entry` widget to shift keyboard focus to itself whenever it's made visible.

The code below shows an implementation doing that. It's based on your code with the important changes indicated with `# ALL CAP` comments to make them stand out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter.constants import *


def doing_stocks():
    name = myaskstring("Input data", "Enter box number:", parent=root)
    name2 = myaskstring("Input data2", "Enter box number2:", parent=root)
    name3 = myaskstring("Input data3", "Enter box number3:", parent=root)


class My_QueryString(tk.simpledialog._QueryString):

    def body(self, master):
        self.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.ok)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.ok)
        w = tk.Label(master, text=self.prompt, justify=LEFT)
        w.grid(row=0, padx=5, sticky=W)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(master, name="entry")
        self.entry.grid(row=1, padx=5, sticky=W+E)
        self.entry.bind('<Map>', self.on_map)  # <--- ADDED.

        if self.initialvalue is not None:
            self.entry.insert(0, self.initialvalue)
            self.entry.select_range(0, END)

        root.update_idletasks()
#        self.entry.focus_force()  # <--- NOT NEEDED.
        return self.entry

    # ADDED METHOD.
    def on_map(self, event):
        self.entry.focus_force()


def myaskstring(title, prompt, **kw):
    d = My_QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
    root.update_idletasks()
    answer = d.result
#    d.destroy()  # <--- NOT NEEDED.
    return answer


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x761")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="")
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Doing Stocks", command=doing_stocks)
button2.place(x = 300, y = 340)

root.mainloop()
```